# Switching between power sources with microcontroller

Tags: led, mosfet, power-electronics, switching, gate-driving

I need a way to switch a load(a high power LED) between two different power sources(50v and 100v) using a logic signal, quickly(<500us) and repeatably. I was going to use an n-channel high side switch on each source, but apparently a high side switch that is boot strapped does not work when the load is just an LED.

Is there a way to make a n-channel high side switch work with an LED as the load

Are they any alternate was I can switch a load between sources?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! There are commercial offerings for the problem you describe but 100 V rating is too high for most of them. Two P-channel MOSFETs with zener diode to clamp the gate voltage and a pull-down network?

Comment: I thought about using pchannel mosfets, but I do not want the off state of the mosfet to be on for the sources, and I will be switching fairly high power so p channel seems less than ideal. Can you give an example of a commercial offering, even if it is outside of my specs?

Comment: What is the _longest_ period of time the circuit needs to handle between voltage changes? _"but apparently a high side switch that is boot strapped does not work when the load is just an LED"_ - cite?

Comment: I don’t see the issue with the source signal, but if the forward losses are a concern to you, your options are limited to somehow pump that gate voltage above your rail. Charge pump comes to mind.

Comment: What actually ***is*** the load? I know it's a "high power LED" but that really doesn't say very much to me.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I was testing high side drivers and they did not work with the LED, it was explained to me that the LED can not properly pull down the bootstrap capacitor to ground when off. I tried with a resistive load and the high side switch worked as expected.  "What is the longest period of time the circuit needs to handle between voltage changes?" Im sorry, I do not understand the question. What does 'handle' mean in this case?

Comment: If the LED voltage is only slightly below the power supply voltage there might not be enough bootstrap voltage. That can be solved with a bleeder resistor. You say the voltage will be switched 'repeatedly'. What is the maximum repetition period? Also what is the purpose of switching between the two voltages?

Comment: One source is used for pulsed over drive, and the other source is used for normal pwm operation. I said that the timing  switching between them needs to be repeatable, or have a low variability. How often i need to switch between sources will be maybe every 500ms or greater. Where would you suggest adding a bleed resistor.